# RSelenium Page not opening

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am attempting to search a page using RSelenium. Right now I am trying to go to mapmyrun.com/routes; later to scrape data.

I have RSelenium up and running through the Docker Toolbox and in the Chrome browser.

I go

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.mapmyrun.com/routes")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

However, while the website opens, any searching fails and I get the error code on the screenshot "This page encountered an error. Please refresh and try again."

Not sure if MapMyRun knows I am using Selenium and is kicking me off?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use https instead of http https://www.mapmyrun.com/routes

Comment: Thank you, but I think the answer is that I need to start off on the main page and go from there to the Find Routes tab. Changing to https did not help